# Is there a function to flip a number to positive to negative and negative to positive?

Tags: java, complex-numbers, negative-number

making a calculator for complex numbers and when dividing i need to use the complex conjugate of a number (basically just means flipping the number around the x-axis) aka make a number positive if it is negative, and negative if it is positive. Flipping the sign seems like something there should be a function for (abs(x) isn't enough here because it needs to go both ways). I am aware that i could just use if-tests to do this, but i feel like there should be some other way to do it.

Comment: What about multiplying the number by `-1`? Or just add a `-` sign.

Comment: What about using x = x * -1;

Comment: lmfao im embarrased I am even attending uni without noticing this. Thank you so much for helping out a dumb friend

Comment: Just be aware 0 returns -0 using x = x * -1 and may not be what you want just throw in an if statement to handle 0

Answer (score 1):

There is no function in the Math class for flipping the sign of a number. You could try converting it to a big decimal and then call negate on that http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/bigdecimal_negate.htm
Or just * -1

Comment: There is no function for it, because there is a negate operator, aka the [Unary Minus Operator `-`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.4), as in `x = -x`. --- Why convert to `BigDecimal` or use multiplication for such a simple operation?!?

Answer (score 0):

> As the Complex Numbers cannot be Totally Ordered, the concept of a negative complex number, relative to a specified zero, is not defined. However, the negative of a complex number is defined as follows:

Let

```
z=a+ib be a complex number.
```

Then the negative of z is defined as:

```
−z=−a−ib
```

Examples:

```
The negative of 2+3i is −2−3i
The negative of 4−5i is −4+5i.
```

Comment: Well yeah complex conjugative is just the imaginary part flipped on its head. Poor wording on my part it came across as if i meant something different.